# Comparing two variables breaks building process

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

I have big problem with comparing strings in SwiftUI. I have declared global observable object called Order:

```swift
class Order: ObservableObject {
   @Published var stationSymbol: String = ""
}
```

and I have some repository of locations:

```swift
class LocationsRepository: ObservableObject {
   @Published collection: [Location] = [
      // here is list of 3 Location objects
   ]
}
```

Location structure:

```swift
struct Location: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let address: String
    let canBeSelectedAsVehicleLocation: Bool
    let stands: [Stand]
}
```

and in my view I'm using it like that:

```swift
@ObservedObject var locationsRepository = LocationsRepository()
    
@EnvironmentObject var order: Order
```

I'm listing all those locations using this:

```swift
ForEach(self.locationsRepository.collection.filter { $0.canBeSelectedAsVehicleLocation }) { location in
```

Everything works dope. I have inside this loop for every location 1 button which sets Order's stationSymbol to Location's name. The thing is that I want to set different bg color and font color of Location's buttons (those inside ForEach loop) so I have code:

```swift
Button(action: {
    self.order.stationSymbol = location.name
}) {
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: "mappin.and.ellipse")
            .padding(.trailing, 10)
            .font(.system(size: 32))
            .foregroundColor(Color("gray-500"))
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(location.name)
                .font(.system(size: 25))
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(Color("gray-800"))
                .padding(.bottom, 5)
            
            Text(location.address)
                .foregroundColor(Color("gray-600"))
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    .padding()
    .background(self.order.stationSymbol == location.name ? Color("blue-700") : Color("gray-200"))
}
.cornerRadius(7)
```

but when I'm trying to add one more short if statement (or if statement for selected location so I can list Location's stands Xcode fails at building and I can't run app. I tried to use LocationRepository as EnvironmentObject and comparing id's (I just changed type of stationSymbol and put there id from Location) but still I have same problem. After the failed build I get an error:

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

I also tried to reinstall Xcode (clearing cache, build folder etc.). I have newest MacOS.

Comment: This error means that the compiler can't infer the type of the expression, since there are too many possibilities. This typically happens in SwiftUI when the body expression is overly long. Do you have anything else in the `body` of the view beyond this button? My guess there's a lot more than this. You'd have to break your view it into smaller views

Comment: You kidding :( ? Ye I have a lot things there but in another views I have lot of code too and it compiles without any problem.

Comment: Best practice for views is to make then small and single-purpose. If you have a long view with tons of stuff, and especially when the compiler complains, it's a to break it down.